# loop over a string and check if it only contains specific characters

Tags: c++

Im trying to loop over a string of DNA sequence to check whether the sequence is a valid DNA sequence or not, I used to code using python but  I'm now trying to learn C++, I found many answers for this question but couldn't find a simple one.
My question is, how I can loop over a string and check whether it only contains a group of valid letters or not ?

this is the same function using python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def isDNA(seq):
    seq = seq.upper()
    flag = True
    for base in seq:
        if base not in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C']:
            flag = False
            break
    return flag
```

and this is my first try with C++, which doesn't work although the logic i think its right!

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

bool isDNA(string seq){
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i =0; i <= seq.length(); i++){
        seq[i] = toupper(seq[i]);
        if (seq[i]!='A' && seq[i]!= 'T' && seq[i] != 'G' && seq[i] !='C'){flag= false;break;}
        }
    return flag;
}



int main(){
    string DNA1 = "ACGT";
    string DNA2 = "acgt";
    string DNA3 = "ATTF";
    string DNA4 = "aafg";

    cout << isDNA(DNA1)<<endl;
    cout << isDNA(DNA2)<<endl;
    cout << isDNA(DNA3)<<endl;
    cout << isDNA(DNA4)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the output is 0,0,0,0 which i supposed to be 1,1,0,0

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Show us input and output!

Comment: Your debugger is your friend. Learning how to use it to step through your code will make your life way easier.

Comment: "doesn't contain a specific character" is not the same as "contains only the allowed characters", which is what your Python code does.

Comment: Also, when using a debugger you will notice that placing multiple statements on a single line makes debugging very hard. There is no penalty to make the code readable, so place separate statements on separate lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i =0; i <= seq.length(); i++)
```

should be

```
for (int i =0; i < seq.length(); i++)
```

You are reading `seq[seq.length()]`, which is 0, and thus not one of the allowed characters, so your function will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i =0; i <= seq.length(); i++)
```

You are reading over the size of the string. If `seq` has a `length()` of 10, it's elements go from [0] to [9]. With your loop you are also accessing element [10] which is not part of the string and your function will return false. Change `<=` to `<`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
bool isDNA(string seq){
        for (int i =0; i < seq.length(); i++){
            char c = toupper(seq[i]);
            if (c !='A' && c != 'T' && c != 'G' && c !='C'){return false;}
            }
        return true;
    }
```

1. As stated by @interjay, you are trying to access `seq[seq.length()]`, which is one past the total size of the `string`. Hence the condition `i < seq.length()`.
2. There is no need to use a `flag` variable. Directly returning from the method also does the trick.
3. Since storing `toUpper()`'s result back into the parameter string only changes the local copy, using a `char` instead improves readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple there are search functions provided by [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_not_of). I don't know if this is faster or slower than the other solutions but it does work.

```
bool isDNA(const std::string &seq) {
    return seq.find_first_not_of("ATGCatgc") == std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer a "translation" from the Python version here.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
//#include whatever toupper is from

bool isDNA(const std::string & candidate)
{
    std::set<char> valid_chars = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'}; // "Initialization list", C++11 only I think
    for (auto c : candidate) // C++ "for in", C++11 req'd
    {
        if(0 == valid_chars.count(toupper(c))) // will return 0 or 1
        {
            return false; // c isn't in valid_chars
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Not as optimized as it could be, but you might find it easier to read.

Also requires C++11 to get in particular "for :" style loops (good for people like me who can't count; no need to think about off-by-one) and auto (if you don't care *too* much about the type).

Comment: The question ain't tagged `C++11`!

Comment: @HappyCoder: It's 2015 and the major compilers (GCC, Clang, Microsoft, IBM, Intel) all support C++11 features.

Comment: @HappyCoder: If that's a constraint then the question should be tagged C++03 or C++98

Comment: Is it so? From my prior experience, new tags are used for newer versions. Only tagging `C++` means C++0x or lower

Comment: @HappyCoder: I don't know if there's a consensus, typically if a question is restricted to a specific standard it should be stated in the question.